# Functions without arguments - what is their role in software design?

Tags: oop, functional-programming, language-agnostic

In his book "Clean Code", Robert Martin states that the ideal number of function arguments is zero. Most people will agree that too many function arguments cause lots of issues. But as far as I can see, a function with zero arguments belongs to at least one of these categories:

1. The function is trivial and always returns the same value.
2. The function lacks referential transparency, its return value depends on external mutable state.
3. The purpose of the function are its side effects.

Now functions of type (1) are not really useful while (2) and (3) should be avoided for well-known reasons.

I am aware that the book I mentioned is about OOP, so functions typically belong to an object and get an object reference passed as an implicit argument. But still, accessing object attributes either means (2) or (3).

So what am I missing?

If you answer this question, please don't just communicate your opinion but provide reasonable arguments or specific examples. Otherwise it will probably get closed.

Comment: The object the method is called on becomes the only argument.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: So you would consider the object reference to be equivalent to an argument, meaning that (2) and (3) do not apply if it is accessed or modified?

Comment: And even (1) in some cases (e.g. incrementally parsing a document).

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams What about a static methods with no input arguments?

Comment: @DStanley: IMO, static methods are a way to force proceduralism onto an objected-oriented language.

Comment: I would remove the qualifiers _external_ and _mutable_ from 2. An immutable object whose methods depend solely on its own fixed state sounds ideal to me.

Comment: A book that reads _The ideal number of arguments for a function is zero_ and only 4 pages later recommends that functions should _Have No Side Effects_ is just crap. Burn it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So what am I missing?

The key word in Martin's statement is "ideal".  If you continue reading, he writes in depth about functions with one, two, and three arguments, but only mentions niladic functions in one context - testing.  He claims that they are trivial to test, presumably because there is only one possible outcome, and it's either right or wrong.

So this is an *ideal*, and the principle to take from it is *the fewer arguments, the better*.  In reality, obviously, this ideal is rarely achieved.  The *purpose* of a function is usually to take input, whether directly, or indirectly through the object or system state (note that I would call those "arguments" as well to be consistent with Martin's analysis), and provide an output.  When you have multiple arguments, the number of test cases increase exponentially, the maintenance is more difficult, etc.

So you are not "missing" anything, so long as you recognize that this is an *ideal goal* and not something that you should take as an *absolute*.

Some examples of "pure" niladic functions in C#:

```
DateTime.MinValue
String.Empty
```

Niladic functions in C# that return object or system state:

```
DateTime.Now()
object.GetHashCode()
String.Length
```

Comment: Your interpretation of the word "ideal" probably explains what Martin meant: It is something that should be aimed at bun not neccessarily needs to be reached completely. But would you say that a function accessing object state still fulfills referential integrity?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "referential integrity" to know how to answer that.

Comment: I was mixing up terms, actually I meant "referential transparency" meaning that when called with the same arguments, the function always returns the same value.

Comment: Ah - then no - certainly functions that reference mutable object state can return different results depending on that state.

Comment: Except when you consider the object to be equivalent to an argument. But then it is no longer a niladic function.

Answer (score 1):

The object's attributes will essentially serve as the arguments to the function. In this way, you can directly manipulate the object you are working with, rather than passing and returning values which you then attribute to the object after performing some behaviour contained in the function.